# Is the heat transfer coefficient in a solid-air interface independent of the temperature of both substances?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Would the heat transfer coefficient change in a solid-air interface if I change the temperature of the solid (or the air)? Assuming everything else remains unchanged (air flow direction, velocity, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heat transfer coefficient is determined by the Reynolds number and the Prantdl number, which depend on viscosity, heat capacity, and density of the air.  These properties all are functions of temperature.  So, the heat transfer coefficient will vary with the solid and air temperatures, but the dependence will typically be pretty weak.